# Keeping column alignment when reading merged cells in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a bunch of tables into a dataframe using pandas. The files have an extension of .xls, but appear to be in HTML format, so I'm using the pandas.read_html() function. The issue I face is that the first column contains merged cells, and pandas is shifting values.

The original file:
[image]

The contents of the pandas dataframe:

[image]

As you can see, some of the values from the second column have been read into the first column. How can I make sure that the values are read into the correct column when one of the columns has merged cells?

Below is the code I'm using to read the files:

```
rawFileDir = 'C:/ftproot/Projects/Korea/Data/AL_Seg/Domestic'
rawFiles = os.listdir(rawFileDir)
for rawFile in rawFiles:
    if not os.path.isfile(rawFile):
        continue
    xl = pandas.read_html(rawFile)
```

Comment: Try `pd.read_fwf('file.xlsx', skiprows=1)` ?

Comment: That seems to read the raw html data. The dataframe now looks like - "<table class="table table6 text-center b_b mb0">".. as values of rows. I'm not sure how I can add a screenshot in the comment.

Comment: If you are reading html, and the output is read in a format you do not prefer, then that's because that's how the original table is, it seems.

Comment: Isn't there a way to read it the same way excel is reading it?

Comment: Read it in excel, save it as a new excel file, and read the excel file instead of the html?

Comment: There are hundreds of these files which need to be read :) which is why I'm trying to do it in code instead of manually.